# How to echo a closing parenthesis literally in an if/else block?

Tags: windows, batch-file

So here is my code:

```
if "!%currentuser%program1!" == "None" (
  REM EASTER EGG this is here because i am not confident with using the not switch
) 
ELSE 
(
  echo 1)!%currentuser%program1!
)
```

And it crashes because where it says:

```
echo 1)!%currentuser%program1!
```

The closing parenthesis is used as an end to the `if` statement but I want it to be literally echoed.
I think the interpreter sees this:

```
if "!%currentuser%program1!" == "None" 
(
  REM EASTER EGG this is here because i am not confident with using the not switch
) 
ELSE
(
  echo 1
)!%currentuser%program1!
)
```

And the last 2 lines are obviously an error.
How can I make it actually echo the closing parenthesis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a caret (^) symbol prefix to the bracket you want to echo.

http://www.robvanderwoude.com/escapechars.php

Answer (score 1):

1. There must be a separator before the opening parenthesis of the `IF` true-condition target
2. That opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the `if`
3. Where an 'else' clause is used, the ending parenthesis of the "true" block, a separator and the `else` keyword must be on the same physical line
4. Where an 'else' block is used, the `else` keyword, a separator and the opening parenthesis of the "else" block must be on the same physical line

ie

```
if condition (
 something
) else (
 someotherthing
)
```

Also, you must escape the literal `)` otherwise batch interprets it as an end-of-block